# OpenTok - cycling camera on iOS degrades video quality

Tags: ios, .net, webrtc, opentok, ios-camera

I've used OpenTok to create a web platform and works fine with Web browsers and Android devices. I've swapped the encoding to support iOS and whenever someone cycles camera on an iOS device, the quality of the video degrades alot making it all fuzzy and sometimes causes the camera feed to freeze.

Is this just an encoding issue? I can't quite figure out why this happens or what causes this?

Comment: no the quality of the video should not degrade. You should check your code and also if possible add your code in the question so that we can know what changes have you done.

Comment: @user832 I believe it may have been a connection issue. We are currently testing it out with users so hopefully it was just me having a bad internet day